# How can I show a confirmation message (not a dialog) without an Alert?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I'm working on a project for a User Interface Design class, so the emphasis is on the UI being as nice to use and non-annoying as possible.  I would like to display a message to the user after they've clicked save, for example, without requiring them to click an OK button.  I'm thinking of the kind of thing you see in gmail if you send a message or do some other actions, where a message appears on the screen, but the message disappears after you do something else.

I'm sure there's a way to do this in Flex (I'm using 4.6), but I just don't know what it is.  I'm pretty new to Flex and I'm having trouble finding anything via Google, because the results keep showing confirmations messages in Alerts; I don't know the search terms to get the results I'm looking for.

Anyway if anyone has ideas or links or anything, I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: How's this look? http://code.google.com/p/flex-toasterlib/ Or http://forums.adobe.com/thread/940927

Comment: A toast message would be an ideal choice. @SamDeHaan, Why don't you make your comment an answer ? :)

Comment: A coworker gave me this link: http://afoucal.free.fr/index.php/2009/07/06/flex-notification/ awhile ago. The author calls them "notifications" instead of toasters, but it's doing the exact same thing.  So there's another option for anyone with the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice Toast library for flex [(flex-toasterlib)](http://code.google.com/p/flex-toasterlib/).

And here's a different Toast class in the adobe forums [(adobe forums)](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/940927).